# Slow manipulation of netfilter rules

Tags: iptables, kernel

I have a script maintaining gre tunnels and firewall rules using the "ip" and "iptables" tools. Setting up hundreds of tunnels, and adresses per interface runs just fine. Takes less than 0.1 second per interface, however when I get around to do the firewall rules everything slows down spending >0.5 per insertion.

Why is it running so slow? What can I do to improve the speed?

It seems like I could try ipset instead, but I really feel there is something wrong with the kernel or something. The interesting thing is that the first 10 rules runs fast, then it slows down..

```
mybox(root) foo# iptables -V
iptables v1.3.5
mybox(root) foo# uname -a 
Linux foo 2.6.18-164.el5 #1 SMP Tue Aug 18 15:51:48 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
mybox(root) foo# cat test.sh
#!/bin/sh

for n in {1..100}
do
  /sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -s ${n} -j ACCEPT
  /sbin/iptables -D OUTPUT -s ${n} -j ACCEPT
done
mybox(root) foo# time ./test.sh

real    1m38.839s
user    0m0.100s
sys     1m38.724s
```

Appriciate any help. Cheers!

Comment: Something may be screwy on your system.  I tried running your test.sh in a Debian VM and it completes in 1.2s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Number one:** Your kernel is ***very*** out-of-date. And so is your `iptables`.

**Number two:** The 'problem' is that for *every* invocation of `iptables`, what happened is:

1. `iptables` pulls the whole table from kernel into userspace
2. `iptables` modifies the table in userspace
3. `iptables` pushes back the table into kernelspace

Rather, configure your `iptables` ruleset the way you want it, then save it using `iptables-save > some_file_name`. The *whole* ruleset will be restored in one fell swoop using the command `iptables-restore < some_file_name`.

(Of course, replace `some_file_name` there with the name of the file you want to save the ruleset in.)

Comment: It was actually a bug, and fixable by upgrading the kernel. However manging this many rules without ipsets was really slow even in the new kernel. So I ended up using ipset.